# Getting "Room cannot verify the data integrity" error message when database schema unchanged

Tags: android, android-room, android-backup-service

I'm currently in the processes of developing my first android app, which implements Room database. Previously I had set android:allowBackup="false" in the manifest as I was continually changing the database schema. Upon changing this to "true", I'm receiving the "Room cannot verify the data integrity" error whenever I uninstall and reinstall the app, even though I haven't changed the database schema, nor anything else in the app for that matter (Room version number unchanged because the schema is unchanged).

I was trying to see if the automatic backup was working and would restore my database on re-installation.

To be clear, the steps followed are:

1. Fresh install of the app (through Android Studio) with android:allowBackup="true"
2. Add entries to the database
3. Uninstall the app
4. Re-install the app (through Android Studio). This is when I receive the error. No changes were made to the app files in Android Studio.

Is this just because I'm installing the app from Android Studio? I'm concerned that when the app is in production, if a user mistakenly uninstalls the app and re-installs the same version (or maybe migrates their apps to a new phone) that they'll get this error and will lose all their data.

Comment: Have you set up a backup account in your device??

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-backup-codelab/index.html#0 here is a codelab that has some shell commands to help you see if the backup is enabled and if backups are working or not

Comment: Yes, my device has a backup account and auto restore enabled. I can see in android studio that the app data is being restored but then it crashes on load with the data integrity error.

Comment: is there anything else in the error log besides what u have posted here?

Comment: can you post your error log?

Comment: I think I have some idea of what's happening now. I tried updating the version number and adding a migration and received an error basically stating that an extra column was found in the old saved version. This column was removed weeks ago, so it seems there is old app data that has been backed up at some point, not from the most recent version and that's what's causing the issue. I need to find out how to delete this old backed up data somehow.

Comment: UPDATE: I deleted the backed up data from Google Dashboard and now I can install the app. I won't know until a backup has been created if data is able to be restored, but it looks like this has solved my problem. Thank you for trying to help. :)